# ASP.NET Core 3.1 URL link to page that requires authorisation giving error Antiforgery token validation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am running a website using ASP.NET core 3.1.8, using MS Identity framework.
Works great, website has been live for a year now.
I want to provide a link in an email to a user, and then when they click that link it will take them to a page that requires them to be logged in to view. The middleware redirects to the login page and user signs in and then returns back to the destination page.

This works fine unless the user already has a tab open in their browser and is already signed in. The user clicks the link and is redirected to the login page (unsure why), then they sign in it goes to an error page 400 as an exception has been thrown:
"**Antiforgery token validation failed. The antiforgery cookie token and request token do not match**"

If I manually copy and paste that link into the browser it doesn't redirect to the login page, just goes straight to the page (as I'm already signed in), even if I just write the URL in Notepad++ and double click on it, it goes straight to the page. It seems to only be a problem if the URL is presented in a `<a href="https://url-to-page">...</a>` and I click on it to take me to the page that I get the problem. I did wonder if was cross site origin related and removed CORS middleware and changed cookie samesite rules to none, but that made no difference.

Here's the relevant parts from Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });

    if (HostingEnvironment.IsStaging())
    {
        // For migrations:
        // Set environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Staging for MariaDbContext
        // $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Staging"
        // Add-Migration -Context MariaDbContext <migration name>
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext, MariaDbContext>();
    }
    else
    {
        // For migrations:
        // Set environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Staging for MariaDbContext
        // $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
        // Add-Migration -Context AppDbContext <migration name>
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection"));
        });
    }

    services.Configure<RecaptchaSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("RecaptchaSettings"));

    // Add singleton services
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSenderSTC, EmailSender>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISimpleLogger, SimpleLoggerFile>(x => new SimpleLoggerFile(Configuration.GetValue<string>("LogFile"), LogLevel.Information));

    // Add transient services
    services.AddTransient<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IGalleryRepository, GalleryRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<ILadderRepository, LadderRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IFileSystem, FileSystem>();
    services.AddTransient<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IClubSparkMembersRepository, ClubSparkMembersRepository>();

    // Add environment specific services
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ISmarterMailRepository, SmarterMailRepoStub>();
        services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaServiceStub>();
    }
    else if (HostingEnvironment.IsStaging())
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISmarterMailRepository, SmarterMailRepoStub>();
        services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaServiceStub>();
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISmarterMailRepository, SmarterMailRepo>();
        services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaService>();
    }

    // Staging environment is on Pi2 with HTTP only so cookie security policy needs to be relaxed
    var cookieSecurePolicy = HostingEnvironment.IsStaging() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = cookieSecurePolicy;
    });

    services.AddIdentity<MemberIdentity, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserManager<AppUserManager>();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = cookieSecurePolicy;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = cookieSecurePolicy;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    //services.AddMvc(options =>
    //{
    //    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    //});

    services.AddHsts(options =>
    {
        options.Preload = true;
        options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    });

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
    });
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AppUserManager userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, AppDbContext context, ISettingsRepository settingsRepository)
{
    if (!env.IsProduction())
        context.Database.Migrate();

    if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsStaging())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    if (!env.IsStaging())
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error?code={0}");
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

I have the controller for where the URL goes to set with attribute [Authorize] and the Action has [HttpGet] attribute

Comment: I guess the reason why your cookie couldn't be passed is according to your cookie settings. I suggest you could try to set the  `options.MinimumSameSitePolicy` to none and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks like it might all relate to the changes that happened within the last year or so relating to SameSite changes in browsers. [SameSite in ASP.Net Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> @Brando Zhang said: "I guess the reason why your cookie couldn't be passed is according to your cookie settings. I suggest you could try to set the options.MinimumSameSitePolicy to none and try again."

Instead of 'SameSiteMode.None' I changed the CookiePolicyOption MinimumSameSitePolicy to SameSiteMode.Lax and removed the ConfigureApplicationCookie options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict so that it will essentially pick up the default of SameSiteMode.Lax.
This seems to have fixed my issue.

Here's my updated ConfigureServices code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsStaging())
    {
        // For migrations:
        // Set environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Staging for MariaDbContext
        // $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Staging"
        // Add-Migration -Context MariaDbContext <migration name>
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext, MariaDbContext>();
    }
    else
    {
        // For migrations:
        // Set environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Staging for MariaDbContext
        // $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
        // Add-Migration -Context AppDbContext <migration name>
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityContextConnection"));
        });
    }

    services.Configure<RecaptchaSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("RecaptchaSettings"));

    // Add singleton services
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSenderSTC, EmailSender>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISimpleLogger, SimpleLoggerFile>(x => new SimpleLoggerFile(Configuration.GetValue<string>("LogFile"), LogLevel.Information));

    // Add transient services
    services.AddTransient<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IGalleryRepository, GalleryRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<ILadderRepository, LadderRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IFileSystem, FileSystem>();
    services.AddTransient<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IClubSparkMembersRepository, ClubSparkMembersRepository>();

    // Add environment specific services
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ISmarterMailRepository, SmarterMailRepo>();
        services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaServiceStub>();
    }
    else if (HostingEnvironment.IsStaging())
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISmarterMailRepository, SmarterMailRepoStub>();
        services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaServiceStub>();
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISmarterMailRepository, SmarterMailRepo>();
        services.AddTransient<IRecaptchaService, RecaptchaService>();
    }

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Secure = HostingEnvironment.IsStaging() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });

    services.AddIdentity<MemberIdentity, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserManager<AppUserManager>();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    });

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddHsts(options =>
    {
        options.Preload = true;
        options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
        options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    });

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
   // app.UseSignalR(routes =>
   //{
      
   //});

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();


    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Landing}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    
    });
```

go like this way because in core 2.2.8 u can write

```
 UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

but 3.0 onward UseEndPoint take the place of routing map of MVC

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion didn't make any difference. I have updated my code samples to reflect the update.